# Cannot use the getContentAsPDF function

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, standardcontroller

**BACKGROUND**

I have a VF page with one field on it:

***Page 1***

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" renderAs="pdf" >
    <apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Quote_Header_Information__c}" escape="false"/>
<apex:page/>
```

The Quote_Header_Information__c is a custom formula field that returns text.

When I open the page in the preview mode it shows as expected and the field contains a proper value. It also shows up in an iframe in another VF page:

***Page 2***

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="QuoteCreatePdfController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
   <apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:outputPanel >
            <apex:iframe src="{!quotePage}" height="550px"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <center>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:commandLink value="Save to Attachments" action="{!saveToAttachments}" />&nbsp;

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </center>

  </apex:form>
```

***Page 2 Contrloller "QuoteCreatePdfController"***

```
public class QuoteCreatePdfController
{

    // Public declarations
    public final PageReference quotePage {get; set;}

    // Private declarations
    private final Opportunity opp;
    private final Id oppId;

    private static final Boolean DEBUG_ON = true;   
     // Constructor
    public QuoteCreatePdfController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // Get the sObject in controller
        this.oppId = (Id)controller.getId();
        this.opp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();

        // Assigng a page to display in the iframe
        this.quotePage = Page.CustomQuote;
        this.quotePage.getParameters().put('id', (String)this.oppId);
    }

    public void saveToAttachments()
    {
        // Retrieve all the attachments in the current sObject
        List<Attachment> attachments = [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :this.oppId];
        if (DEBUG_ON) System.debug('>>> [saveAttachment] => [attachments]: ' + attachments);

        // Create a name for attachment
        Integer attNumber = attachments.size() + 1;
        String attName = this.opp.Name + '_Quote_' + String.valueOf(attNumber) + '_' + String.valueOf(Date.today()) + '.pdf';
        if (DEBUG_ON) System.debug('>>> [saveAttachment] => [attName]: ' + attName);

        // Get the content of the quote page as blob
        Blob content;
        if (Test.IsRunningTest())
        { 
            content = Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST'); 
        }   
        else
        { 
            try
            {
                if (DEBUG_ON) System.debug('>>> [saveAttachment] => [this.quotePage.getUrl()]: ' + this.quotePage.getUrl());
                content = this.quotePage.getContentAsPDF();
                //content = Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST');
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
                throw new AttacmentsException('An unexpected error has occurred while saving the attachment. Contact your administraton for more details.');
            }
        }

        // Create an attachment
        if (DEBUG_ON) System.debug('>>> [saveAttachment] Creating attachment...');
        Attachment att = new Attachment();
        att.Name = attName;
        att.Body = content;
        att.ParentId = this.oppId;
        // Save into the database
        try
        {
            insert att;
        } 
        catch (System.DmlException e)
        {
            System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            throw new AttacmentsException('An unexpected error has occurred while saving the attachment. Contact your administraton for more details.');
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

Everything works fine until I click the "Save to Attachments" button on Page 2. I am getting the following error:

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested
>   field: Opportunity.Quote_Header_Information__c

The problem is in this line of code

```
content = this.quotePage.getContentAsPDF();
```

I found this doc [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_render_in_apex.htm?search_text=getContentAsPDF) with a similar example and it works just fine. It's very annoying that Page 1 can be rendered as PDF, but it cannot provide its content with the getContentAsPDF() function if object's fields are provided by standard controller only.

**QUESTION**

Are there any ways to use only standard controller for Page 1? Or the only option I have is using a custom controller for Page 1 that will provide all that fields as instance members?

Comment: Try adding a rerender attribute to apex:commandLink

Comment: What do I need to provide in the reRender attribute? Id of the Opportunity object?

Comment: Have an empty outputPanel and giving its id. And give the id of that element to command link. It will do a partial page refresh. I guess you would want to also display a success or failure message based on the save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom controller for Page 1 and retrieving necessary fields via SOQL.

**Page 1**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CustomController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" renderAs="pdf" >
    <apex:outputText value="{!Opportunity.Quote_Header_Information__c}" escape="false"/>
<apex:page/>
```

**CustomController**

```
public class CustomController
{
    public Opportunity opp { get; set; }
    // Constructor
    public QuoteCustomController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // Get the sObject in controller
        Id oppId = (Id)controller.getId();
        this.opp = [SELECT Id, Quote_Header_Information__c,
                    FROM Opportunity 
                    WHERE Id = :oppId LIMIT 1];
    }
}
```